# lighttpd rewrite-once issue

Tags: url-rewriting, lighttpd

Have a Python/fastcgi application that serves web pages (.html) and to download packages (.tar.gz). The problem is that lighttpd (on the host) is not finding the .js and .css files to display the web pages correctly.  It seems to be an incorrect url.rewrite-once which is written as:

```
url.rewrite-once = (
    "^/favicon.ico$" => "/assets/favicon.ico",
    "^/assets/(.*)$" => "/assets/$1",
    "^/(.*)$" => "/$1"
)
```

Is this correct?

Comment: How do you request the .js and .css files that aren't getting served? what is their path on the server? The last two rewrites, what is their purpose? Consider setting `server.errorlog` and `debug.log-request-handling = "enable"` to get a picture of how lighttpd is handling requests.

Comment: Thank-you. Will set the two suggested parameters and see what is going on from there.